# Trouble creating a function in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql-server

I'm used to working in MS SQL Server, so MySQL is always a little bit foreign to me. I wrote the following for MS SQL Server, and I'm trying to port it to MySQL:

```
CREATE FUNCTION ToRadians
(@Degrees float)
RETURNS float
AS
BEGIN
  DECLARE @Radians float
  SELECT @Radians  = @Degrees * 3.1415927 / 180
  RETURN @Radians
END
GO
```

I've got

```
CREATE FUNCTION ToRadians
(@Degrees float)
RETURNS float
BEGIN
  DECLARE @Radians float;
  SELECT @Radians  = @Degrees * 3.1415927 / 180;
  RETURN @Radians;
END
```

but in PHPMyAdmin, that gives me the error:

```
Error

SQL query:

CREATE FUNCTION ToRadians(
@Degrees float
) RETURNS float AS BEGIN DECLARE@Radians float;

MySQL said: Documentation
#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '@Degrees float)
RETURNS float
AS
BEGIN
DECLARE @Radians float' at line 2
```

The searching I've done indicates that the above MySQL UDF *should* be correct, but it obviously isn't. SELECT version() returns 5.0.77

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Don't use @ in MySQL variable names, it creates a local session variable.
2. You probably need to change standart delimiter which is semicolon to another character, for instance // :
   `DELIMITER //` before your function definition, then `//` just after function, then switch delimiter back to semicolon (`DELIMITER ;`)

Comment: Also, it turns out I can't use SELECT to do math within a function. I should have been using SET Radians = Degrees * 3.1415927 / 180;

Comment: You could also do `SELECT ... INTO [variable]`…

Answer (score 1):

```
CREATE FUNCTION ToRadians (in_degrees FLOAT) RETURNS FLOAT
DETERMINISTIC
BEGIN
    RETURN in_degrees * 3.1415927 / 180;    
END;
```

DETERMINISTIC because the return for a given value of degrees should always be the same in radians.

Also DEGREES() and RADIANS() functions already exist in mysql.
[RADIANS()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/mathematical-functions.html#function_radians)

Comment: I did not know that function existed. Fancy.